# How to pass file through Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form with file inputs

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="sdfgsdfg" name="sdfgsdfg">
    <input required type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="pic_1" id="pic_1"/>
    <input required type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="pic_2"/>
</form>
<input type="button" class="validate" value="validate"/>
```

When I click on my button, I use ajax

```
$('.validate').on('touchend click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let myFile = $('#pic_1').prop('files');
    let test = new FormData();
    test.append('pic',myFile[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendfiles.php",
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        data: test,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          console.log('success pdf mail');
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

**sendfiles.php**

```
$pic = $_FILES['pic'];

if(file_exists($pic)) // returns false
```

I cannot get this file and send it by email. How can I do that ?
If I make a console.log of my FormData

```
for (var pair of test.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
}
```

it shows

pic, [object File]

Comment: `$pic` is __array__. What do you expect from `file_exists(ARRAY)`?

Comment: @Cid - Yes you can. The OP is on the right path, they just need to read up on how to [handle uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) in PHP.

Comment: Can you? I'm sure I had this problem.. Or probably, that's the download that can't be done with AJAX...

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILE);` in PHP show you?  Your JavaScript/jQuery looks fine.

Comment: @Cid - Y, downloads are a bit trickier since the browser doesn't parse ajax responses. You could probably make it work somehow with some clever and inventive JS magic.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that was about a year ago and did something else to serve files. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: `mimeType: "multipart/form-data",` — Don't do that.

Comment: You need to handle the uploaded file in PHP before it's available! https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php